# Better to use "and" or "in" when chaining "let" statements?

Tags: coding-style, ocaml, scope, ml, let

I realize this is probably a silly question, but...

If I'm chaining a bunch of `let` statements which do *not* need to know each other's values, is it better to use `and` or `in`?

For example, which of these is preferable, if any:

```
let a = "foo"
and b = "bar"
and c = "baz"
in
  (* etc. *)
```

or

```
let a = "foo" in
let b = "bar" in
let c = "baz"
in
  (* etc. *)
```

My intuition tells me the former ought to be "better" (by a very petty definition of "better") because it creates the minimum number of scopes necessary, whereas the latter is a scope-within-a-scope-within-a-scope which the compiler/interpreter takes care to note but is ultimately unimportant and needlessly deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question "which is better?" only really makes sense when the interpretations do not differ.  The ML family of languages (at least SML and OCaml) have both a parallel initialization form (`and`) and a sequential, essentially nested-scope form (`in`) because they are both useful in certain situations.

In your case the semantics are the same, so you are left to answer the question "what reads best to you?" and maybe (if this is not premature) "which might be executed more efficiently?"  In your case the alternatives are:

- For the `and` case: evaluate a bunch of strings and do a parallel binding to three identifiers.
- For the `in` case: bind `foo` to `a`, *then* bind `bar` to `b`, *then* bind `baz` to `c`.

Which reads better?  It is a toss up in this case because the outcome does not matter.  You can poll some English speakers but I doubt there will be much preference.  Perhaps a majority will like `and` as it separates bindings leaving the sole `in` before the expression.

As to what executes more efficiently, I think a good compiler will likely produce the same code because it can detect the order of binding will not matter. But perhaps you have a compiler that generates code for a multicore processor that does better with `and`.  Or maybe a naive compiler which writes all the RHSs into temporary storage and then binds them, making the `and` case slower.

These are likely to be non-essential optimization concerns, especially since they involve bindings and are probably not in tight loops.

Bottom line: it's a *true* toss-up in this case; just make sure to use parallel vs. sequencial correctly when the outcome does matter.

Answer (score 6):

My opinion is that `in` is better. The use of `and` implies that the definitions are mutually dependent on each other. I think it is better to be clear that this is not the case. On the other hand, some OCaml programmers do prefer `and` for very short definitions, where the slightly more compact notation can appear cleaner. This is especially true when you can fit the definitions on a single line:

```
let a = "foo" and b = "bar" in
```

Comment: Can they be mutually dependent even if *not* using `let rec`?

Comment: As nimrodm said, the following does not work (meaning that `and` might not always imply dependence): `let a = 3 and b = a + 7 in (* ... *)`

Answer (score 2):

I would say in is better because it reduces scope and better expresses intent.  If I see all these defintions chained together in a shared scope manner I would be under the impression that it was done for a reason and would be looking for how they effect each other.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as the difference between `let` and `let*` in Lisp, I believe.
`let*` (similar in functionality to the `in..in..` structure - the second structure in your question) is sometimes used to hide *imperative* programming since it guarantees sequential execution of expressions (see what Paul Graham had to say about let* in [On Lisp](http://dunsmor.com/lisp/onlisp/onlisp_7.html)).

So, I'd say the former construct is better. But the truth is, I think the latter is more common in the Ocaml programs I have seen. Probably just easier to use in letting one build on previously named expressions.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about guaranteed sequential execution; thanks for reminding me of that.